# GNU make unexpected behaviour

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I want `make` to build all `.cpp` in the directory with tracking header changes. I attempt to do it by first making gcc output a target with dependencies with `-MM` option and then append the body to that target that will actually call the compilation:

```
OPTIONS = -std=c++11 -Wall

export

all : $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))


%.o : %.mkt
    make -f $*.mkt

%.mkt : %.cpp
    gcc $(OPTIONS) -MM $*.cpp > $&.mkt1
    echo gcc $(OPTIONS) -c %.cpp > $*.mkt2
    cat $*.mkt1 $*.mkt2 > $*.mkt
```

Yet somehow this script issues the calls of the form

```
g++ -c -o something.o something.cpp
```

for each `.cpp` file in the directory. The temporary files `.mkt1`, `.mkt2` and `.mkt` are not created. Why does this happen? How do i achive desired behaviour? I'm doing this on windows with mingw.

Comment: Does it help if you take out the spaces after the commas in the `patsubst` invocation?

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't the `mkt` files have tabs for indentation if you intend to use them as Makefiles?

Comment: @tripleee removing spaces has no effect. `.mkt` files should indeed have tabs, my bad, but here they aren't even created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have supplied a chain of two pattern rules (`%.cpp`->`%.mkt`, `%.mkt`->`%.o`), but Make already has a single implicit rule (`%.cpp`->`%.o`) which it will find first, when searching for a way to build `something.o`.

The simplest way to solve the problem is to use `make -r` (or `make --no-builtin-rules`) which will disable the built-in implicit rule.

Comment: [User defined rules override the built-in rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules). Don't think this is the right answer.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, a user-defined *rule* overrides a built-in *rule*. But the OP has not defined a rule for `%.o: %.cpp`. When Make looks for a way to build `something.o`, it finds the built-in rule (and no user-defined rule) and looks no further. If the built-in rule is disabled, Make looks further, finds the chain and uses it.  I have tested this with GNU Make 3.81, but if you can show me that I am wrong I will be grateful.

Comment: `-MM` flag causes gcc generate lines in the form of `x.o : x.cpp`. I guess the intention of the author is to append a recipe to such a dependency, but he missed a tab in the second line of `%.mkt` recipe.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, that's true, and that isn't the only problem in that command, but it's a moot point unless/until the OP can execute the `%.mkt` recipe.

Comment: Another way to achieve this without relying on command line options is to add `.SUFFIXES:` somewhere in the Makefile. This may be a little too drastic, though, depending on what's in the rest of the makefile.